# Problem in retrieving a decrypted data

Tags: java, ms-access, encryption

I am working on encryption-decryption program.
Program gets an input from the user and encrypts it. Then it stores the encrypted data in ms access database table.
Later, the data is retrieved from the table , decrypted and given back to the user.

I am storing the data as text in the ms access. The encryption algorithm returns a byte array of size 16.
But when i retrieve the data from the database, i am getting a byte array of size 8 only.
Help me to get through this...

Comment: Are you using the MS Crypto API, a home grown method or an algorithm copied from a web page?

Comment: @ur384636: forget MS Crypto API, you can solve your problem by convert the cipher bytes to string and store the result string in string filed in DB. when you need the cipher text read the string from DB then convert it to bytes.

To perform convertion from string to bytes and from bytes to string using many methods, one of them is to use the BASE64 Encoder/Decoder, see the example in my answer:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187166/problem-in-retrieving-a-decrypted-data/3187720#3187720

other way to store the bytes in "binary field" in DB, also see my answer,

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are using it as text while it isn't (it is binary data). The halving of the length sounds like a Unicode related issue (i.e. the 'text' is stored as wide with two bytes for character, but retrieved as one byte per character).

Comment: thanks, but is there any compatible datatype for storing binary data?

Comment: It's not necessary to use a BLOB field if you do the appropriate conversions on retrieving and storing data.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is to encode the cipher text as String using [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding

you can use Appache Commons Library for that:
http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

**Edited**:
i dont know why you want MS-ACCESS Specific solution ! the DMBS may change, the OS also may change.. you must to write general solution that can work in many cases..

here small example for using Base64 Encoder/Decoder:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder; 

import java.io.IOException ;

public class Decoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        byte[] cipherBytes = "stackoverflow".getBytes();    // say this the is encrypted bytes

        String encodedBytes = new BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherBytes);
        System.out.println("stored as: " + encodedBytes );

        byte[] decodedBytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encodedBytes); 
        System.out.println("extracted as: " + new String(decodedBytes) );
    }
}
```

**Note: this code using Internal Sun Classes (BASE64Encoder/Decoder) and its not recommended to use these classes in your program because it may change in the next version of JDK.**

using BASE64 Encoder/Decoder in Appache Commons is better.

if you want the MS-ACCESS solution, try to store the ciphertext in LONGBINARY , see this:
[How to specify blob type in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002026/how-to-specify-blob-type-in-ms-access)

Comment: Note his tags.  How can this be used inside MS Access?

Comment: if you read the wiki article: "base64 encode binary data by treating it numerically" you want to store binary data ? there is many options, the first is store the binary in "binary field" is the DBMS you work with. second option that i prefere, is to convert binary data (cipher text) to textual format, then store the result in normal string field, as you store users names. you can apply this by using Base64 encoding, you encode cipher text then store it in db.

when you want the ciphertext from db you will preform the opposite operation, decoding string.

Comment: And how can this be used inside MS Access? That is, your reponse to Tony's inquiry does not include anything Access-specific at all, and the question is about Access. -1

Comment: This question is not Access-specific at all! There is a Java tag on the question, so presumably the OP is writing Java code to talk to the database. This solution is fine and will work with just about any database.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that stores encrypted credit card numbers using the MS Crypto interface. I got the code from the MS Knowledge Base, and the key thing is running ByteToString() and StringToByte() conversion in the proper places. I'm storing the actual data in a plain Jet text field and have had no problems whatsoever.

Comment: -1 ByteToString() and StringToByte() conversions is not related to MS-ACCESS. these is converter/encoder methods and anyone can write similar methods without using MS Crypto interface! don't use/copy/paste code without understanding of what the code do.

Comment: There is sample VB code in the Knowledge Base article, and the point is that if you convert from string-to-byte and byte-to-string, it doesn't matter if you use a text data type for storing your encrypted values. The point is that you have to keep track of where you need to convert, and that was the point of my citing the method I used in Access -- not because it was Access-specific, but as an example of how you avoid issues with the data type you're storing the encrypted value in.

Comment: your right and i agree with you. This convertion work as (encoder/decoder) method work, in the end they convert from bytes to string and from string to bytse.. see the example in my answer. so why you not like my answer and decrease it while its smiliar to your answer, they both convert from bytes to string and from string to bytes (whereas my answer is also better than your solution because its independent from MS-Crypto API ). plz think twice before you hit decrease/increase button because it's unfair. with regards.