# Storing a secretkey in the database and retrieving it

Tags: java, encryption

I am doing a project on password encryption and decryption using AES algorithm.
I need to store the key of type SecretKeySpec in the database(ms-access) and have to retrieve it.
How can i do this?
I have created a column in the database of type oletype object.
I am using a query:

```
String query="insert into encrypt values(?)";
```

how to set the parameter in the query?

Comment: duplicated :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187166/problem-in-retrieving-a-decrypted-data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Access supports the type **OLE Object** to store MS-documents and binary data like `pictures, sounds, or other binary data`. With the constraint that "**they've to be created in other programs using the OLE protocol, that can be linked to or embedded in a Microsoft Access table. You must use a bound object frame in a form or report to display the OLE object.**"

I like to suggest to use MS SQL Server or MySQL (engines) so that you can impose many **integrity** and **consistency checks** more **efficiently and effectively**. MySQL provides a way to store binary values with `BLOB` type. SQL Server provides `binary` and `varbinary` for the same purpose...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a `PreparedStatement`, for example:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into encrypt values (?)");
ps.setBytes(1, rawKeyBytes);
ps.execute();
```

I'd suggest that you don't use `oletype`; probably better to make it a blob. Remember that a key is just an array of bytes. Don't try to store the `SecretKeySpec` - store the raw key bytes instead.