# How to add BLOB column in database?

Tags: c#, image, blob, oledbcommand, oledbexception

I have read that **for saving images into my database** I need a datatype called **BLOB**. Also, in this link [Microsoft Access Data Types](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp), that for adding a column BLOB in my database working in Microsoft Access I need ***Ole Object***. So I have done some tries like this one:

```
public partial class alterOneSec : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = DAL.GetConnection();
        con.Open();
        if(con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            string sql = "ALTER TABLE item ADD picture OLE";
            OleDbCommand cmd = DAL.GetCommand(con, sql);
            int num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(num == 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("homepage.aspx?err=error");
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("homepage.aspx?err=case3");
    }
}
```

I want to add a column **picture** to my database in the table **item** where I can save pictures that people attach for example. I tried also `string sql = "ALTER TABLE item ADD picture OLE OBJECT` and `string sql = "ALTER TABLE item ADD picture BLOB"`all this three cases throw an exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Syntax error in field definition.
```

How do I add this column for pictures? ***Thanks!***

Comment: Use LONGBINARY as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002026/how-to-specify-blob-type-in-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

`ALTER TABLE item ADD picture LONGBINARY`